# Assigning one array to another inside a merge method

Tags: java, arrays, merge, array-merge

I am trying to merge to arrays nums1 and nums2...

m = size of filled elements in nums1
n = size of nums2

An array is passed by reference in a method...So if any change occur inside a method, it will reflect outside it...So then I assign `nums1 = result` inside `merge` method...it's showing inside the the merge method, when I print the nums1 array by below code:

```
    System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(nums1));
```

..So the nums1 array will now point towards "result" array..
but when I try to print the same inside the "main" method by the code below:

```
System.out.println("Merged Array: " + Arrays.toString(nums1));
```

Then it's not showing the desired result.i.e nums1 should show the "result array values" as change din the "merge" method..

Please someone explain why this is happening?

My entire code of merging the two arrays is as below:

```
public class MergeSortedArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] nums1 = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, nums2 = {2, 5, 6};
        
        int m = 3, n = 3;
        
        System.out.println("Original Array: nums1: " + Arrays.toString(nums1));
        System.out.println("Original Array: nums2: " + Arrays.toString(nums2) + "\n");

        
        
        merge(nums1, m, nums2, n);
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Merged Array: " + Arrays.toString(nums1));
        
    }
    
    
    public static void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
        
        int n1idx = 0, n2idx = 0;
        
        int[] result = new int[nums1.length];
        
        int ridx = 0;
        
        while(n1idx < m && n2idx < n) {
            
            if(nums1[n1idx] < nums2[n2idx]) {
                
                result[ridx++] = nums1[n1idx++];
                
            } else {
                
                result[ridx++] = nums2[n2idx++];
                
                
            }
        
        }
        
        // fill the remaining elements from nums1
        while(n1idx < m) {
            
            result[ridx++] = nums1[n1idx++];
            
        }
        
        // fill the remaining elements from nums2
        while(n2idx < n) {
            
            result[ridx++]= nums2[n2idx++];             
        
        }
            
        nums1 = result;
        
        System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(nums1));
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `result` to `nums1`, it does not change the reference in the called program.  It is of local significance only.  This is because the actual reference is passed by value and you can't change that with a simple assignment.

However, any changes you make to `nums1` contents in the merge method will be reflected in the calling program since you are changing what the reference refers too and not the reference itself.

Everything in Java is passed by value.  Even arrays and objects.

Here is an example.  The Identityhash shows a value indicative of the reference.  Note that after the last assignment in the method, the passed reference was not changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] q = {4,5,6};
      System.out.println("q in main = " + System.identityHashCode(q));
      callMethod(q);
      System.out.println("q in main = " + System.identityHashCode(q)); // hasn't changed
}

public static void callMethod(int[] v) {
    System.out.println("v in method = " + System.identityHashCode(v));
    int[] otherArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
    v = otherArray;
    System.out.println("v in method after assignment = " + System.identityHashCode(v));
    
}
```

Prints

```
q in main = 925858445
v in method = 925858445
v in method after assignment = 798154996
q in main = 925858445
```

Comment: yes, I know that..but you didn't answer my question..since array is passed by reference inside a method..so when it to another array inside the method, then it should now refer to the new array..why these chnages inside the method is not reflected in "main" method..? I have a "conceptual doubt"..please explain it.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my answer.